# mercurial over ssh, no suitable response from remote hg

Tags: linux, ssh, mercurial

When I run `hg clone ssh://user@host/repo_dir` i get a "no suitable response from remote hg" and "There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!". What is causing this? I do have ssh access to the server/files involved.

If i run `scp -r user@host:/repo_dir ./` i get all the contents of the repo, including `.hg` just fine. same for `ssh user@host "ls /repo_dir"`

adding `-v` does nothing. output is exactly the same. same for `-vvv`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that i had the wrong syntax. Mercurial uses the scp/ssh style for referencing files, and that expects double slashes when the filepath is absolute, as it was in my case.

Alternative is to either use a symlink in your home, or add two slashes for the root fs one.

instead of:

```
hg clone ssh://user@host/repo_dir
```

use:

```
hg clone ssh://user@host//repo_dir
#                        ^
```

Comment: @Peter edit my post to say it does follow scp/ssh path style, but i disagree. on scp `host/path` will get `/path` at the root. mercurial will get `/home/user/path`. scp uses `:` to separate `host` from `path`. anyway just being pedantic :) here is the vague standard if anyone cares http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-01#page-2